# Java - cross platform mobile development

Tags: java, mobile

Are there really any tools out there or sdk's that truly support cross-platform java mobile development, and are worth their weight in code?

I would like to rewrite our mobile application with an sdk that would allow usage on IOS (Ipad and Iphone), Android, and Windows Mobile 5 and 6.

If I am asking for the moon, please let me know.

I am traditionally a c# developer, and just moving into learning Java.

I see many different posts about cross-platform development but I wonder where we are as an industry today on this.

Comment: It sounds like you really want HTML + JavaScript + CSS.

Comment: I have read a bit on HTML5 and such tools as NSBASIC and the like.  Also, to prevent code exposure using a tool such as PhoneGap, you can create a native application.  I am leery at the moment of the idea because I am not sure that HTML5 (at this point) can handle all of my needs.  It seems fairly limited in advanced functionality.

Comment: All platforms have their limitations.  It's hard to know what "limited" means when we don't know anything about your requirements, other than "cross-platform" and "works on mobile".

Comment: The application needs to support serial port printing / bluetooth printing / serial port communication (interfaces to other devices for data transmission) and signature capture

Answer (score 6):

You could take a look to the [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) or the [codenameone](http://www.codenameone.com/) framework.

Answer (score 1):

For a server-based app built in pure Java but deployed via pure HTML+CSS+JavaScript: [Vaadin](http://www.vaadin.com/). But that means your app requires an Internet connection to run.

Tip: Some folks build a bare-bones minimal native app that simply points a web-browser view directly to your site's URL. This allows you to sell/give your "app" in the App Store while actually building a web app that runs cross-platform.

There is no Java present on iOS. So there is no Java-based development kit to build local native apps across iOS, Android, and Windows Mobile.

Google did announce the [J2ObjC](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/) project to translate Java code to Objective-C for the iOS. But that does not solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Tabris](http://eclipsesource.com/en/products/tabris/) is another option but it isn't free (It isn't costly either).